# How can I create a NetworkX subgraph from nodes with specific degree?

Tags: python, networkx

I've a graph `G` which includes my whole dataset, but what I want to do now is create a graph from this where a subset of the nodes have `degree` above a certain threshold.

This in a roundabout way is to plot the most connected nodes, but which I can then change the threshold value to my choosing for other plots.

So my code currently is:

```
myedgelist = []

for i in G.degree(): 
    if i[1] > 2:
        myedgelist.append(g for g in G.edges(i[0]))
```

But if I try to create a subgraph from these edges with `G.edge_subgraph(myedgelist)` this results in a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this solution using the `nx.subgraph` function:

```
G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=100,p=.05)
node_degree_dict=nx.degree(G)
G2=nx.subgraph(G,[x for x in G.nodes() if node_degree_dict[x]>5])
```

Comment: NetworkX 2.2 returns a `DegreeView` which needs to be converted to a `dict`. So: `node_degree_dict=dict(nx.degree(G))` if you're intending for node_degree_dict to be a dict as the name implies. But you can't access dict elements by index?

Comment: I'm using 2.2. You are right that `DegreeView` objects are not exactly dictionaries, but in this case they work in the same way and you can look up nodes like this: `node_degree_dict[x]`. The "keys" of this object are the nodes of the graph `G`. Give it a try.

Comment: `KeyError: 0` . How does that list comprehension work? What is it doing? EDIT: "The "keys" of this object are the nodes of the graph G" - My main graph is `G` so shouldn't you declare `G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=100,p=.05)` as `H=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=100,p=.05)`, i.e. so H and G are different objects?

Comment: It returns a list of all nodes of G which have degree greater than 5. Could you share your code?

Comment: I am just defining G via erdos_renyi_graph to have an example graph. You can skip that line, defining G as you did before.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will check.

Comment: Try running the code I shared without the line defining G. It was just an example.